# Qualys warn for spring vulnerabilities geoserver and geowebcache

Tags: spring, geoserver, geowebcache

Qualys reports that there are severe vulnerabilities in geoserver and geowebcache relating to the spring files. At the moment we run geoserver 2.20.4 and geowebcache 1.20.3, but still getting these vulnerabilities.

Which versions of geoserver and geowebcache are CLEAN?

Answer (score 0):

Please respect the project's [responsible disclosure guide lines](https://geoserver.org/comm/) - if you have an urgent need to have fixes applied to the project then you should do it yourselves or contract with a [commercial supplier](https://geoserver.org/support/) to do it for you.

Disclosure: I work for one of those suppliers.